# How to access Iphones call timer

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

this is my first time posting so if I make a mistake correct me please!

I am currently brain-storming an app, and as I have been researching part of it on here, and other places I have come to a bit of a snag. I want the app to be able to access the call timer on a iPhone (as in, it will be able to track how long you are in a call) and then store this information. As of 2011 it seems that this was either not possible, or you had to use something called CoreTelephony. I however could not find any recent material on this, so I was wondering if anything has changed in recent years.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to count/show how long someone has spent on the phone from the iphone usage data you cannont, If you are trying to show how long someone has been on the phone in your app using your phone/voip or what ever you use then you can use NSTimer

Comment: Ok Im thinking what I want to do may not work then. Basically I was hoping to make an app that would allow would find and store how much phone time you've spent on particular contacts, and then be able to use that info with other processes